# How to modify each item in the dictionary with the value from the rest of others items in the same dictionary combined exhaustedly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined this "expand_re" function which search for the pattern in the dictionary value and replace match by the value in the same list(dictionary):

```
def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}):
    for i in pat_dict:
        for pattern in pat_dict:
            temp = re.compile(r'#'+pattern+'#')
            pat_dict[i] = re.sub(temp,r'('+pat_dict[pattern]+')',pat_dict[i])

pd = dict(a='correct',b='#a#',c='#b#',d='#c#',e='#d#',f='#e#',g='#f#')
expand_re(pd)
print('result =',pd)
```

I got the result:

```
result = {'e': '(((#a#)))', 'd': '((#a#))', 'g': '(#e#)', 'f': '(((((correct)))))', 'a': 'correct', 'c': '(#a#)', 'b': '(correct)'}
```

I know it suppose to be:

```
    # produces/prints the dictionary 
    # {'d': '(((correct)))',
    #  'c': '((correct))',
    #  'b': '(correct)',
    #  'a': 'correct',
    #  'g': '((((((correct))))))',
    #  'f': '(((((correct)))))',
    #  'e': '((((correct))))'
    # }
```

So my question is how do I repeat the "replace everywhere" until no values in dictionary contain any replaceable tokens? My output is like 50% correct ?!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve and why you want to do it nor how you thought of doing it.

Comment: Hi Erik, because I have to modify each item in the list with the result from the rest of others items in the same list combined

Comment: I have no idea what you just meant... you don't even have a list; you have a dictionary. and what does it mean to *"modify each item with the result from the rest of the items combined"*??

Comment: Hi Erik, I already turned the dictionary to the list.

Comment: `for x in list(some_dict):` is exactly equivalent to `for x in some_dict:` so no, you have not changed anything... and in any case, calling `list(...)` on a dict does not convert the dict itself, so you still have a dict.

Comment: Hi Erik, I meant "modify each item with the value from other items in the same list"

Comment: I *still* don't have a clue what that means. Maybe it's better if you rewrite your question to include WHY and WHAT you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think your homework wants you to repeat the "replace everywhere" until no values in dictionary contain any replaceable tokens.

Comment: Hi Erik, I just re-edit my question.

Comment: Hi Arkadiy, that exactly what I meant !

Comment: Posted an answer that produces exactly the output you described with Python 3.x as well as Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import re

VAR_PATTERN = re.compile(r'#(\w+)#')

def expand_re(pat_dict: {str: str}):  # remove type decl for Python 2.x
    pat_dict = dict(pat_dict)  # make a copy; don't ever modify input parameters

    def substitute_var(matchobj):
        var_name = matchobj.group(1)
        return '(' + pat_dict[var_name] + ')'

    while True:
        found_ref = False

        for key, val in pat_dict.items():
            newval = re.sub(VAR_PATTERN, substitute_var, val)
            if newval != val:
                pat_dict[key] = newval
                found_ref = True

        if not found_ref:  # no more names to replace
            break
    return pat_dict


pd = dict(a='correct',b='#a#',c='#b#',d='#c#',e='#d#',f='#e#',g='#f#')

print('result =', expand_re(pd))
```

**OUTPUT:** (formatted)

```
result = {
    'a': 'correct',
    'b': '(correct)',
    'c': '((correct))',
    'd': '(((correct)))',
    'e': '((((correct))))',
    'f': '(((((correct)))))',
    'g': '((((((correct))))))'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to sort the items you're iterating over. Use `sorted(pat_dict)` instead of `pat_dict` in your `for` loops.

Comment: Even if that's the only problem in his algorithm, I think sorting does not work in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 2 simpler answers

- One involved sorted and reversed sorted list:

  ```
  def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}):
     for i in sorted(pat_dict):
        for pattern in reversed(sorted(pat_dict)):
            temp = re.compile(r'#'+pattern+'#')
            pat_dict[i] = re.sub(temp,r'('+pat_dict[pattern]+')',pat_dict[i])
  ```
- Other one is comprehensive:

  ```
   def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}):
       for lhs_to_exp,rhs_to_sub in pat_dict.items():
           lhs_comp = re.compile('#'+lhs_to_exp+'#')
           for lhs,rhs in pat_dict.items():
               pat_dict[lhs] = lhs_comp.sub('('+rhs_to_sub+')',rhs)
  ```